# How to add one column values with respect to other column in sql

Tags: sql

```
Name    QTY
Jones   4
Smith   1
Smith   1
```

This is the output of my query. now i have to add last column values with respect to the names.
i should get the output as

```
Jones 4
smith 2  (1+1)
```

how should i do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Have a look at GROUP BY and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Group By`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [`Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) the `QTY` values in each group:

```
SELECT Name, Sum(QTY) As SumQuantity
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY Name
```